# ISS SSTV transmission times

Tags: satellites, sstv

Unfortunately, the ISS SSTV transmissions scheduled to the next weekend had to be canceled. Anyway, I'm planning to capture some images and have a doubt. I've been trying to find some answers, but no success this far.

My doubt is: during the days of the transmissions (let's suppose, the next saturday and sunday), do the transmissions usually happen continuously, or they happen at specific times (For instance, at scheduled times or while the Station is passing over specific countries/regions)?

Putting it in other words: may I expect that the Station will be transmitting during all the passes over my QTH, or I would have to be a little "lucky" to have the station transmiting something while passing over my location?

Answer (score 2):

The SSTV transmissions were originally already scheduled for late December. I'm waiting for them, too.

In the past, the ISS was relatively continuously transmitting pictures in a loop, the same 4-5 pictures multiple times with small (some minute long) breaks in between. 
It is very easy to spot the ISS signal in a waterfall, it's quite strong and you will see the Doppler shift/drift very easily.

I had really good luck receiving pictures in last April and have recorded 5 absolutely clear images.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, friend. What model of antenna did you use?

Comment: I was using a X-300N, which really isn't ideal for sat-com, but it works. A QFH antenna would probably work much better.